# Ui Grid Pagination in header template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to include pagination in header of Ui Grid. Somehow, the header itself stops displaying. Please let me know where I am wrong.
Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yxZoCeZumH9n2RpPtr6h?p=preview)

```
<div role="rowgroup"
 class="ui-grid-header">
<div class="ui-grid-top-panel">
    <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">
        <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">
            <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper"
                 ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()">
                <div role="row"
                     class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix"
                         ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
                         ui-grid-header-cell
                         col="col"
                         render-index="$index">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div role="row"
                     class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">
                   <div ui-grid-pager></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pagination is at footer only, I think we cann't use it in the header

Comment: In ng-Grid we created a custom header template with pagination. However, in UI-Grid facing problem. There must be a correct way to do this.